# Stop Triggering Event on Page Load

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8.1

I have a CheckBox with `IsChecked="true"` property and `Checked` event:

```
<CheckBox Checked="myChBox_Checked" IsChecked="True" />
```

I don't want to trigger the `Checked` event on page load. Because I use other Controls in the method and I get `NullReferenceException`:

```
private void myChBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    myComboBox ... // NullReferenceException
}
```

What am I supposed to do to stop the triggering from startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example:

- subscribe in *Page.Loaded* event:

  ```
  this.Loaded += (sender, e) => myChBox.Checked += myChBox_Checked;
  ```
- or maybe better just check in your event for `null`:

  ```
  private void myChBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
       if (something == null) return;
       myComboBox ... // NullReferenceException
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for null reference in the event handler, or assign it in the page `Loaded` event handler:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page 
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += page_Loaded;
    }

    private void page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myChBox.Checked += myChBox_Checked;
    }

    private void myChBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (myComboBox != null)
        {
           myComboBox ... // Should not be null, but check anyway
        }
    }
```

}